# Using P5.js, how can you change Pixel values of a .PNG file?

Tags: javascript, colors, png, p5.js

I am writing a game in Javascript using P5.js, and the sprites I created are from .png files.  They were created in black.  Is there a way to recolor the images to another color? Does anyone have any sample code they could post on how to do this?

Thanks so much!

I tried writing this- doesn't work

```
var adjImage= images[0];
  for (y = 0; y < adjImage.height; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < adjImage.width; x++) {
      var pixelValue= adjImage.get(x,y);
      if (pixelValue[0]== 0 && pixelValue[1]== 0 && pixelValue[2]== 0) {
        pixelValue= color(0, 0, 255);
      }
    }
  }
  image[0]= adjImage;
```

Comment: Pixel values are arrays of 3 elements [Red, Green, Blue, Alpha]. You can change the tone of the pixels by adding some constant to one of those channels. For example, if you increase the Red values by let's say 10, you will get the image to look more redish. Please show us your code and your attempt and we can try to help you. Take a look at  https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image 
 and https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/pixels

Comment: Hi Sembei, I just updated my post with an attempt. Thanks!